# Cannot re-order launch bar icons after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, icons

I've just upgraded to 22.04 jammy jellyfish, and I find that my favourites in my launch bar are reordered. Before, I cloud long-click on an icon and drag it to a new location in the launch bar, but now a long click just opens the context menu.

How do I reorder items in my launch bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hold down quite so long. Hold and drag almost immediately. Start dragging as soon as the background of the icon illuminates.

Here's a video showing it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tcgwz1S9pNM